# sort a list-tuples from smallest to largest (using only loops and conditions without built-in sort )

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.8

I arranged a list of numbers from smallest to largest In the following way :

```
my_list = [-5,3,0,9,-8,1]
for i in range(len(my_list)):
  for x in range(len(my_list)-1):
    if my_list[x] > my_list[x+1]:
      my_list[x], my_list[x+1] = my_list[x+1], my_list[x] 
print(my_list)
```

output is : `[-8, -5, 0, 1, 3, 9]`

Now I have a list of tuples :

```
list_tuple = [(1, 5), (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 1)]
```

I want to arrange them the same way from smallest to largest by element [1]
To be like this :

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)]
```

Without using built-in sort

Comment: Just change `if my_list[x] > my_list[x+1]:` to `if my_list[x][1] > my_list[x+1][1]:`.

Comment: @Samwise that's not even necessary, tuples can be compared directly and will compare element by element.

Comment: OP said "compare by element[1]" so I'm assuming they want something that works if the first elements don't happen to all be the same -- otherwise their existing code would already work and there'd be no problem to solve.  :)

Comment: @Samwise wouldn't be the first time that someone had a working program and didn't realize it.  The problem here is that the task is not well enough specified, which also isn't the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list_tuple = [(1, 5), (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 1)]

n = len(list_tuple)

for i in range (0, n):
    for x in range (0, n-i-1):
        if list_tuple[x][1] > list_tuple[x+1][1]:
            y = list_tuple[x]
            list_tuple[x] = list_tuple[x+1]
            list_tuple[x+1] = y

print (list_tuple)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)]
```